# Filter to the latest month and then filter to the best score per person

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've got a Google Sheet which holds the results of a monthly competition. The format is

```
Name       | Date       | Score
--------------------------------
Alan Smith | 14/01/2016 | 500
Bob Dow    | 14/01/2016 | 450
Bob Dow    | 16/01/2016 | 470
Clare Allie| 16/01/2016 | 550
Declan Ham | 16/01/2016 | 350
Alan Smith | 10/02/2016 | 490
Bob Dow    | 10/02/2016 | 425
Declan Ham | 12/02/2016 | 400
Declan Ham | 12/02/2016 | 390
Clare Allie| 12/02/2016 | 560
```

I want to do 2 things with this data

1. I want to create a new sheet which holds the latest 'best' results. For the data presented here that would be

   ```
   Alan Smith | 10/02/2016 | 490
   Bob Dow    | 10/02/2016 | 425
   Declan Ham | 12/02/2016 | 400
   Clare Allie| 12/02/2016 | 560
   ```

   i.e. The results from February with the 'best' score per person. Here Declan Ham's lower score of '390' was removed.
2. I want another sheet to hold the tournament ranking. People are ranked by their top 3 monthly scores. i.e. The best score for each person for each month is obtained and the top 3 scores are combined to give their place in the tournament.

So far I've attempted to use Google queries, vlookups, filters to get these new sheets. But, just focusing on 1), the best I've been able to achieve is

```
=FILTER(Results!$A:$B, MONTH(Results!$B:$B) = MONTH(MAX(Results!$B:$B)))
```

Which will get me the results from the latest month. But it does not remove duplicates entries by people.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can achieve these requirements? Feel like I'm treading water at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to remove duplicates, you need to identify the maximum score by each person; you can do that by grouping values by person, then aggregating using `max()`. Here's how that would look, for the month of February 2016:

```
=query(Results!A1:C,"select A,max(C) where todate(B) > date '2016-2-1' group by A")
```

Instead of using a fixed value for the start of the latest month, we can get the year and month using spreadsheet formulas, and concatenate our query with them:

```
=query(Results!A1:C,"select A,max(C) where todate(B) > date '"&year(max(Results!B2:B))&"-"&month(max(Results!B2:B))&"-1' group by A")
```

[image: screenshot]

That addresses your first question.

#### Tournament ranking

Your second goal is too complex for a single spreadsheet formula, in my opinion. Here's a way to accomplish it with multiple formulas, though!

[image: screenshot]

The X & Y axes are filled out by spreadsheet formulas. On the X axis (orange), we populate participants names using this in cell `A3`:

```
=unique(Results!A2:A)
```

The Y axis consists of dates (green). These are the start dates of each unique month that there are scores for, calculated using the following formula in cell `D2`. This results in strings, e.g. `2016-01-1`, and that format is specifically required for the later formulas to work.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(Results!B2:B13,"YYYY-MM-1")))))
```

Here's the formula for cell `D3`, which will calculate the sum of the 3 highest scores recorded for the user whose name appears in `A3`, for the month appearing in `D2`. (Copy & Paste the formula across the full range of participants & months, and it will adjust.)

```
=sum(query(Results!$A$1:$C,"select C where A='"&$A2&"' and todate(B) >= date '"&B$1&"' and todate(B) < date '"&IF(ISBLANK(C$1),TEXT(TODAY()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd"),C$1)&"' order by C desc limit 3 label C ''"))
```

Key points about that formula:

- The query range needs to used fixed values so it isn't transposed when copied to additional cells. However, it's still open-ended, to absorb additional rows of scores on the "Results" sheet.

  ```
    Results!$A$1:$C
  ```
- A `WHERE` clause is used to select rows from the `Results` sheet that are for the given participant (`A='"&$A2&"'`) and fall within the month that heads the column (`C$1`).

  ```
    ...and todate(B) < date '"&IF(ISBLANK(C$1),TEXT(TODAY()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd"),C$1)&"'
  ```
- The best 3 scores for the month are found by first sorting the above result descending, then limiting the result to 3 rows.

  ```
    ...order by C desc limit 3
  ```
- Finally, the `QUERY` headers are suppressed by this little trick, so that we get a single number as the result:

  ```
    ...label C ''
  ```

Individual tournament totals appear in column `C`, with a range `SUM` across the row, e.g. for cell `C3`:

```
SUM(D3:3)
```

The corresponding ranking in column `B` is then:

```
RANK(C3,C$3:C)
```

#### Tidy

For simpler copy/paste, you can do some error checking in these formulas, so that they can be placed in the sheet before the corresponding data is - for example, at the start of your season. Using `IF(ISBLANK(...` or `IFERROR(...` can be very effective for this.

- B3 & down:

  ```
    =IFERROR(RANK(C3,C$3:C))
  ```
- C3 & down:

  ```
    =IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",sum(D3:3))
  ```
- D3 & rest of field:

  ```
    =IFERROR(sum(query(Results!$A$1:$C,"select C where A='"&$A3&"' and todate(B) >= date '"&D$2&"' and todate(B) < date '"&IF(ISBLANK(E$2),TEXT(TODAY()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd"),E$2)&"' order by C desc limit 3 label C ''")))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively for the first part of your question (the latest 'best' results) , in addition to the solution provided by Mogsdad, this should also work.. :-)

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A2:A), sort(A2:C, 2, 0, 3, 0), {1,3}, 0)))
```

[image]

EDIT: This formula sorts the table with dates (col B) descending and col C descending and then (ab)uses the fact that vlookup only returns the first match to return the first and last column.

Comment: does not work for me. I've modified it to =ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(Results!A1:A), sort(Results!A1:G, 3, 0, 7, 0), {1,7}, 0))). as the real data goes from A:G. But when I use this formula it does not eliminate duplicate entries for people who shot in previous months but not the latest.